# Algorithm for vector difference upon itself

Tags: algorithm, matrix

What is the fastest known algorithm for computing the difference of a vector upon itself.

If i have a row-vector A with dimension n x 1 and i take the transpose A'. Then how can i compute the differences between the elements the fastest way possible?

$$

\begin{matrix}
s_1 \
s_2 \
\cdots \
s_n \
\end{matrix}

\begin{matrix}
t_1 \
t_2 \
\cdots \
t_n \
\end{matrix}

$$

Comment: you mean that for a fixed vector s_i, how to get a matrix defined as A_{i,j}=s_{i}-s_{j}?

Comment: Correct. Apparently mathJax doesn't work on stackoverflow :/

Comment: you could use twice the function `dger` provided by LAPACK, it calculates A:= \alpha x*y^T + A, so one starts with A=0, in the first round \alpha=1, x=s, y=e (where e is a vector e_i=1 for all i) and in the second round \alpha=-1, x=e, y=s

Comment: To my understanding, if `n` is the length of the vector, the output would have `n*n` values, so no algorithm can have a running time better than `O(n*n)`; however, calculation of the pairwise differences would be such an algorithm with running time `O(n*n)`, which in a certain sense would be optimal.

Comment: The algorithm i currently use has a quadratic running time. But i'm not entierly sold on the n*n. Currently i calculate only one half of the matrix since the resulting matrix is symmetric.

Comment: I don't geht it - so you mean symmetric up to sign?